# On a multi socket system how to determine compatibily between different cpu models?

Tags: cpu, compatibility, xeon, processor-socket

I know that when using a multi socket motherboard, the normal rule is to use several times the same cpu model.

But a split appeared in recent years which reached Intel: cpu which delivers more total performance does it at the expense of reducing per thread performance which penalize single thread workloads (where the computer does only one single threaded task one taking full ram).

So my idea is mixing the 2: taking a cpu which delivers good per thread performance and a different model still compatible with the [same motherboard](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192596/intel-server-system-r2308wftzsr.html) and a different one for delivering more performance for workloads which can run in parallel.
In my case this means https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=202780,192472

But in general, how to determine compatibility between cpu when both are compatible with the motherboard?

Comment: Ok, so authoritative reference was set in this [manual](https://www.intel.fr/content/www/fr/fr/products/docs/processors/xeon/2nd-gen-xeon-scalable-datasheet-vol-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Multi socket boards need the same cpu types on the board to work well. Some CPU types do work together, but they will run at the speed of the slowest processor. So you are basically throwing away money in my opinion. As far as I know, they also need to have the same TDP, which isn't the case here.

See these posts on our sister board Server Fault for additional information:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/420312/can-i-mix-two-cpus-with-a-different-clock-speed-on-a-board/420314#420314
- https://serverfault.com/questions/650426/two-different-intel-xeon-e5-24xx-on-one-dual-socket-motherboard

Comment: So what does this means in practice with https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=202780,192472?